# numpy.vectorize of function that returns an array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize a function which has 2 inputs, and outputs a np.array, of shape =(4,). The function looks like this:

```
def f(a, b):
    return np.array([a+b, a-b, a, b])
```

I was able to vectorize the function, using the signature parameter, however it only works if I exclude one of the parameters using the `excluded` argument of `np.vectorize`:

**This works:**

```
vec = np.vectorize(f, signature='()->(n)', excluded=[1])
x = np.arange(5)
y = 3
vec(x, y)

>> output:
array([[ 3, -3,  0,  3],
       [ 4, -2,  1,  3],
       [ 5, -1,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  0,  3,  3],
       [ 7,  1,  4,  3]])
```

However if I take out the `excluded` argument, things don't go as planned.

**This does not work:**

```
vec = np.vectorize(f, signature='()->(n)')
x = np.arange(5)
y = 3
vec(x, y)

>> Error:
TypeError: wrong number of positional arguments: expected 1, got 2
```

How can I make the vectorized function able to receive an array/list of input values for either one (or both) of the input parameters?

The expected output would be a `vec` function which would enable calling it with multiple inputs for either one of the input parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [237]: f1 = np.vectorize(f, signature='(),()->(n)')                          
In [238]: f1(np.arange(5),3)                                                    
Out[238]: 
array([[ 3, -3,  0,  3],
       [ 4, -2,  1,  3],
       [ 5, -1,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  0,  3,  3],
       [ 7,  1,  4,  3]])

In [241]: f1(np.arange(5),np.ones((4,5))).shape                                 
Out[241]: (4, 5, 4)
In [242]: f1(np.arange(5),np.ones((1,5))).shape                                 
Out[242]: (1, 5, 4)
```

---

`frompyfunc` returns a object dtype array:

```
In [336]: f2 = np.frompyfunc(f,2,1)                                             
In [337]: f2(np.arange(5), 3)                                                   
Out[337]: 
array([array([ 3, -3,  0,  3]), array([ 4, -2,  1,  3]),
       array([ 5, -1,  2,  3]), array([6, 0, 3, 3]), array([7, 1, 4, 3])],
      dtype=object)
In [338]: _.shape                                                               
Out[338]: (5,)
```

`np.vectorize`, without the `signature`, uses `frompyfunc`, but adds its own `dtype` conversion.

---

```
In [340]: f1(np.arange(5), np.arange(3)) 
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

This fails for the same reason the following addition fails:

```
In [341]: np.arange(5)+np.arange(3)                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-341-fb1c4f4372da> in <module>
----> 1 np.arange(5)+np.arange(3)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,)
```

To get a (5,3) result we need to make the first argument (5,1) shape:

```
In [342]: np.arange(5)[:,None]+np.arange(3)                                     
Out[342]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Rather monosyllabic by your standards ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer, I have mixed feels about this signature method.  It's an interesting idea, but it runs even slower than the regular `vectorize`.

Comment: @hpaulj, I would expect another behavior... perhaps vectorize is not the function I should be using? For the case of `f1(x, y)`, where x has n elements, and y has m elements, I would expect to be returned an array of dimensions n x m, where each element is `f(x_i, y_j)` for `0<i<n, 0<j<m`.
Then each element of this array would itself be a 4-item vector, as output by f(a,b)

Comment: @hpaulj not sure why we need to pass a 2-dim array as the second parameter. I would expect to call `f1(np.arange(5),np.arange(3))` and get a shape (3, 5, 4)

Comment: The (4,5,4)  array is a (n, m, 4) array.  I just added a `frompyfunc` example that creates a (n,m) object dtype array, where each element is 4 element array.

Comment: I've added a broadcasting example.  The whole point to using `np.vectorize` is to let us apply broadcasting to functions that otherwise don't use it.  It's a convenience tool, not a performance one.