# Custom "inner product" / "outer product"

Tags: numpy, numpy-ufunc

I have the following code structure:

```
result_matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(data1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data1.shape[1]):
        result_matrix[i,j] = myfct(data1[i,:], data2[:,j])
```

Can we solve this with a more numpy-y way - possibly with `ufunc`?

Comment: Depends on - `myfct`.

Comment: @Divakar: actually the point is to define your own "product" arbitrarily, not to find a solution to some edge cases.

Comment: All ufuncs support broadcasting so if your ufunc takes two arguments you can do `ufunc(x[:,None],y)`.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html

Comment: So `myfct` is an arbitrary function that takes two 1d arrays as input, and returns a scalar?  There are ways of wrapping it to hide the python level iteration, but no code to turn it into a fast compiled function.  For that you have to look outside of `numpy`.

Comment: @tch: ufuncs seem to work on the elements, not on the rows of data1 and data2. I don't see how to change that behavior. If you know how to do it after all, please show a specific example.

Comment: @Make42, yes,the ufuncs act on scalars, however if you apply them to an array then they follow the broadcasting rules (see the broadcasting section in my first comment). Thus, if `myfct` is a ufunc, you can use broadcasting to take advantage of the complied function and avoid a python loop. You can create custom ufuncs using `frompyfunc`, but like @hpaulj notes, it won't turn it into a complied function.

Comment: `frompyfunc` uses broadcasting rules to pass scalar elements to the function.  `vectorize` has a `signature` that lets you pass 1d (or other) arrays to the function, but it's even slower.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330169/numpy-vectorize-of-function-that-returns-an-array